# PHP dynamic THIS-> in a class

Tags: php

Hey guys working on a database extended class and I'm having one problem on my update and delete i want to make the where part dynamic see this code

```
$sql .= " WHERE ".static::$identifier." = ". $db->escape_value($this->utID);
```

I'm using Late Static Bindings i want the utID to be dynamic because not every table uses utID it could change from table to table

I tried to use static but that doesn't work.

Any help to get this to work would rock, thanks everyone...

Comment: what do you mean by __doesn't work__?

Comment: I tried to use 

$sql .= " WHERE ".static::$identifier." = ". $db->escape_value($this->static::$identifier);

wanting the utID to change from class to class and it gives error

Comment: You were asked what the error message is.